# Adding button on top of a picture

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uistoryboard

I want my buton on top of my image. Lets say I have an image on my storyboard and I want to see my button too. Also I want to do the same thing to UIWebview...

Comment: In the left, you choose your object. The lower it is in the colum, the upper it is on the view.
In other words : UIImageView|UIButton, and your button will be over your UIImageView.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY MUCH :) IT WOOOORKED :D

Answer (score 1):

In storyboard, you can select the thing you want to move (the button of the imageview), then `editor > arrange > [direction you want]`.

The different directions are:

- `Send to front`
- `Send to back`
- `Send forward`
- `Send backward`

A combination of these should allow you to achieve the order you want.